# javascript set multiple style values

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to set gradients via javascript like on this site http://www.mediaevent.de/css/gradient.html

target:

```
<div style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); 
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); 
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); 
            background-image: linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);">
</div>
```

javascipt:

```
var progress_ele = document.getElementById("progress");    
progress_ele.style["background-image"] = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, "+this.color+" "+(this.percent-2)+"%, white "+(this.percent+2)+"%)";
```

Question:

how can i set the other attributes for browser compatibility? i dont think overwriting the array will help.

Comment: Add them all to the value and separate them using comma's.

Answer (score 0):

Here's JSFiddle code I wrote for you: **http://jsfiddle.net/SwZv6/1/**

You can create a CSS class for your inline styles as follows:

```
.progress {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);
}
```

And bind it to your progress element as:

```
var progress_ele = document.getElementById("progress"); 
progress_ele.className = "progress";
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your work, but i cannot usw a css class since its some dynamic stuff. the progress bar will be updated via javascript since a class with fixed values would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var progress_ele = document.getElementById("progress");    
progress_ele.style["background-image"] = "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, "+this.color+" "+(this.percent-2)+"%, white "+(this.percent+2)+"%),
-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+this.color+" "+(this.percent-2)+"%, white "+(this.percent+2)+"%),
-o-linear-gradient(left, "+this.color+" "+(this.percent-2)+"%, white "+(this.percent+2)+"%),
linear-gradient(left, "+this.color+" "+(this.percent-2)+"%, white "+(this.percent+2)+"%)";
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try to set `style` attribute directly ?

```
progress_ele.setAttribute("style", "background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); background-image: linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);")
```

Comment: question: if i use style. i would overwrite any existing styles. thus i would need to take care, if there is any other style applied like display:none if the progress bar is hidded.

Comment: i think you can't set multiple value through this `progress_ele.style["background-image"]` .... you can add to current `style` like `var s = progress_ele.getAttribute("style"); s += "some style"; progress_ele.setAttribute(s);`

Comment: even when you set multiple value through `progress_ele.setAttribute`, when you read this `progress_ele.style["background-image"]`, latest value has been set on that... to check by yourself, first add `style` attribute like `progress_ele.setAttribute("style", "background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%); background-image: linear-gradient(white 0%, #9FBFD2 100%);")` and then read this `progress_ele.style["background-image"]`